# How can I run an npm script for an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deployment?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My `package.json` has:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node_modules/.bin/coffee server.coffee",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test node test/runner.js",
    "coverage": "NODE_ENV=test COVERAGE=1 node test/runner.js -R html-cov test/ > ./test/coverage.html",
    "testw": "fswatch -o test src | xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c 'coffeelint src server.coffee ; npm test'",
    "db:drop": "node scripts/drop-tables.js",
    "encryptConfig": "node_modules/.bin/coffee config/encrypt.coffee",
    "decryptConfig": "node_modules/.bin/coffee config/decrypt.coffee",
    "postinstall": "npm run decryptConfig"
  },
```

When I deploy to Elastic Beanstalk, I'd like to run the `postinstall`, but apparently it doesn't do that. Okay, no problem.

I created a file called `.ebextensions/00.decrypt.config` which has:

```
commands:
  00-add-home-variable:
    command: sed -i 's/function error_exit/export HOME=\/root\n\nfunction error_exit/' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh

container_commands:
  02-decrypt-config:
    command: $NODE_HOME/bin/npm run decryptConfig
```

However this doesn't seem to run either.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Try to enclose your commands in quotes, that's a requirement

Comment: Also, not sure if $NODE_HOME is working - could you run simple test like echo $NODE_HOME > /tmp/test.txt?

Comment: Can you check /var/log/eb-activity.log and /var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log. Those files will tell you what happened when these commands were executed.

Comment: @sap1ens - please make an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions:

- Try to enclose your commands in quotes, that's a requirement
- Also, not sure if $NODE_HOME is working - could you run simple test like echo $NODE_HOME > /tmp/test.txt?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a workaround for this issue. The `npm` binary on an EB instance is located in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-{version}`. You should make sure this is present in your `PATH` first.

**00_setpath.config**

```
commands:
  01_set_path:
    command: echo 'export PATH=$PATH:`ls -td /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-* | head -1`/bin' >> /root/.bash_profile
  02_set_path:
    command: export PATH=$PATH:`ls -td /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-* | head -1`/bin
```

As you can see I am appending to `.bash_profile` and also adding `PATH` to the current shell. The former should be sufficient for your purpose. I added the second one as I'm using the `npm` command within a script in my `package.json`, and it seems these scripts are run inside the same shell. TL/DR: You should now be able to use `npm` in both places.

As for your npm scripts, try using `prestart` instead of `postinstall`.