# How do I run an arbitrary npm script on an Elastic Beanstalk instance

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to debug an issue with a Node application running on Elastic Beanstalk.  The issue appears only under EB, and I can't reproduce on a dev machine, even when running with production configuration locally.

Unlike other EB platforms, the Node platform really seems to go out of its way to hide the Node bin/ path so you can't run npm or node commands from a shell.  I realize that you don't normally want to operate this way under EB, but I also need a shorter debugging feedback loop than waiting 5 minutes for an EB deploy to test every little tweak.

Piecing together information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811302/how-can-i-run-an-npm-script-for-an-aws-elastic-beanstalk-deployment) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260116/how-do-i-run-npm-update-g-npm-on-elastic-beanstalk) I understand where the pieces are, but what is the most straightforward way to run a simple `npm run script` command?

Answer (score 6):

Once logged in:

1. Choose your node version:

   `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v8.11.1-linux-x64/bin/`
2. Run your command:

   `cd /var/app/current/
   npm ls`

Answer (score -2):

1. To debug an issue on your elastic beanstalk instance you just need to SSH to your machine (you can find details in EC2>Instances section in WEB AWS console: https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2 ). Then debug your code on that machine.
2. If you can't ssh to elastic beanstalk instance and you still need to run some script after deployment you can do it by placing `.ebextensions` a folder in your app root folder and create script that will be fireup on some specific event. More information you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26804625/6541812

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this is all basic EB information that is obvious from the documentation. It should be implicit from the question that I am talking about running commands interactively once I am already ssh'ed into the box. Apologies if that was not clear.